# embedding a local pdf file in google chrome packaged apps

Tags: pdf, embedded-resource, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use the embed tag in a chrome packaged app to display a pdf document included in the distribution. The renderer displays "Looking for plugin...". Is the chrome pdf viewer supported in packaged apps or is the problem with the embed tag?

```
<embed src="document.pdf#page=33" type="application/pdf">.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet for opening a pdf?

Comment: I haven't looked at this for a while. I didn't pursue this further because the answer was that the chrome packaged apps environment doesn't provide the chrome pdf viewer so I would have to save the pdf and use the installed platform pdf viewer, this wasn't an acceptable solution for me so I abandoned my move to packaged apps for the moment. pdf.js and node webkit which includes the viewer are alternative solutions you could pursue.